# JS Error in sp.runtime.debug.js

Tags: 2013, javascript

```
sp.runtime.debug.js?rev=VFkBZgkYpbAZS6abSrBqIg%3D%3D:2814 Uncaught Sys.ArgumentNullException: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

This is in: sp.runtime.debug.js

```
SP.ClientRuntimeContext = function SP_ClientRuntimeContext(serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl) {
    this.$1F_0 = {};
    if (!serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl) {
        **throw Error.argumentNull('serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl');**
    }
    if (!serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl.startsWith('/') && !(serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl.toLowerCase()).startsWith('http://') && !(serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl.toLowerCase()).startsWith('https://')) {
        throw Error.argument('serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl');
    }
    this.$w_0 = serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl;
};
```

the error is on this line:

`if (!serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl) {
        throw Error.argumentNull('serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl');
    }`

The value of serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl is empty ("")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, This was caused by a null error in the code behide. It was trapped inside an empty try/catch. The code never set my hidden fields needed for sp.runtime.js

Answer (score 1):

can you set a breakpoint on this line and get the values of `serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl`?

```
if (!serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl.startsWith('/') && !(serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl.toLowerCase()).startsWith('http://') && !(serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl.toLowerCase()).startsWith('
```

Comment: The Value of serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl is empty ("")

Comment: so how about look at the call stack and see what function is executed before it calls the sp.runtime.debug.js? It could be the function that is calling the runtime is not passing the objects properly or it has an error that is causing this issue.

Comment: sorry, i found the error.  It was caught in an empty try-catch.

Comment: awesome, so it is solved now?